# Need to show id in href tag but not navigate into other page

Tags: php, javascript

I need to show item id in a href tag ,but it must not navigate into other page... one way to prevent navigation is using jvascriptvoid(0) but can i append it to id... If so how??

```
 <a href="id='.$portfolio_id.' "><img height="57" width="57" src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'"></a>
```

Comment: onclick="return false;" should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onclick="return false;"` to your anchor tag. This will prevent the link from being navigated to.

```
<a href="id='.$portfolio_id.' " onclick="return false;"><img height="57" width="57" src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'" /></a>
```

However, I don't understand the point of this, and this isn't want the anchor tag is designed for. Perhaps if you supply more information we can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an `<a>` tag in first place. You can always use another kind of tag to display information. Specially since the contents of your `href` attribute aren't really valid links. Using an `id` attribute in your enclosed `<img>` should be even better.

```
<img id="'.$portfolio_id.'">
```

Or adapting your layout would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a click event and return false, this will stop the browser from navigating to the href.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{

    document.getElementById("mylink").onclick = function()
    {
        return false;
    }

}

</script>


 <a id="mylink" href="http://google.com"><img height="57" width="57" src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "#" character in-front of the id, it wont navigate to other page.

```
<a href="#id='.$portfolio_id.' "><img height="57" width="57" src="images/portfolio_uploads/orig_'.$portfolio_item['image'].'" /></a>
```